# How use cx_oracle in VS code?

Tags: python, oracle, visual-studio-code, cx-oracle

I am getting error when `import cx_Oracle` in vs code (python):
`Error: Unresolved import cx_Oracle`.

I have installed the extension as well but still have error.

Any clue?

Comment: How did you install the extension? According to the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python): "Packages are installed using the Terminal panel and commands like `pip install <package_name>` (Windows) and `pip3 install <package_name>` (macOS/Linux). VS Code installs that package into your project along with its dependencies".

Comment: You need to install a package using `pip install cx_oracle`, and you need to install [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/pl/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html) for the package to work correctly.

Comment: Also make sure that once you install the package you select the appropriate environment in VS Code itself.